# $elemMatch range query syntax

Tags: mongodb

I am using [this solution](https://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/47178201123/mongodb-indexing-tip-3-too-many-fields-to-index) for indexing messages with many varying fields. Specifically, I am using Solution#2.

The example of range syntax

```
db.generic2.find({"props": { $elemMatch: {$gte: {"prop1": 6}, $lt: {"prop1": 99999999 } }}})
```

I have never seen this syntax in MongoDB docs, rather I see everywhere syntax like

```
db.generic2.find({"props": { $elemMatch: {"prop1": {$gte: 6, $lt: 99999999 }}}})
```

What is the difference? Funny using the first one I get fast query using indexing, using the second I get a slow query with collection scan. Both results are correct, however different.